# is it possible to authenticate as a google user inside app hosted on gcloud using IAM?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-iam

Suppose I have an app hosted on google cloud: Frontend and Backend. The requirement is that the app can only be used by users within a specific group or with a specific role, etc. within a specific google organization (to which the project which contains the app belongs).

I thought of implementing it like this:

1) The Frontend would require the user to login with his google account (which I expect to be tied to the Google Cloud organization) using Google as a 3rd party authenticator. Since the app is build with node/javascript that's easily done with some `npm` package such as `passport`. After the user signs in from the browser and the specific redirects occur Google should provide the backend with information about the user including a unique identifier.

2) The Backend (running either on app engine, compute engine, etc. shouldn't matter) should access a Google Cloud specific API which should identify the user and whether the user belongs to a group, or to the organization, basically anything that would help. It is assumed that the machine will have a service account with all necessary roles to access said APIs and determine if the user is OK or not.

3) If the user is OK then a session will be created on the Backend for the user and as long as that session lives the Backend will know the identity of the requests, so everything should be fine.

The problem I've encountered lies on step 2: looking through the whole Google IAM, APIs, documentation videos, etc. I couldn't find any way to a) identity the user based on an unique ID and b) verify that either the user is part of a group (via a separate membership resource or otherwise) or if it has a specific role associated, which would be equivalent to my use case.

Any idea if:

1) my approach makes sense and this is even possible?

2) if so then what resources or methods I should use to make it happen?

3) if not then what approach would be appropriate for my use case?

Comment: Stupid question but, did you try to directly authorize googles groups in you oauth? I don't really know how it's done but that's how you authenticate in grafana for exemple, if you enable google oauth, you give him a list of "domains" authorized to connect. And after that you must specify users.

Comment: @night-gold haven't found any helpful documentation for anything in that regards. what I can say that both the users and the groups need to be "contained" inside the gcloud project or otherwise maybe be a private gsuite package with users and groups, the solution is open in that regards.

Answer (score 2):

The key question is who will be your Identity Provider?

The next key question is how will you map the user's identity from the Identity Provider to your own database of users / privileges.

The next key question for you to decide on is which type of OAuth 2.0 to use. Implicit OAuth or 3-legged OAuth. Implicit OAuth is done in the browser and only involves the Client ID. 3-legged OAuth involves the web server for receiving tokens and is considered more secure.

> 1) The Frontend would require the user to login with his google
>   account (which I expect to be tied to the Google Cloud organization)
>   using Google as a 3rd party authenticator. Since the app is build with
>   node/javascript that's easily done with some npm package such as
>   passport. After the user signs in from the browser and the specific
>   redirects occur Google should provide the backend with information
>   about the user including a unique identifier.

You can use any Identity Provider (Google, Facebook, Auth0, Okta, etc.). (Note: see my comment further down about Google IAM). Implementing OAuth in the browser is so simple to do that you really do not need a library. However, if you want to use a library there are many to choose from. However, pick a library that is native JavaScript and not an node package. Node packages tend to create huge files that users must download.

Once the OAuth flow completes, you will have two tokens. An Access Token and an ID Token. The ID Token is what your JavaScript front end will include in requests. I will ignore the Access Token in this answer, but it can be used to directly access GCP services such as Google Storage if setup correctly in the authentication phase. For this answer I am assuming that you want the identity of the user.

> 2) The Backend (running either on app engine, compute engine, etc.
>   shouldn't matter) should access a Google Cloud specific API which
>   should identify the user and whether the user belongs to a group, or
>   to the organization, basically anything that would help. It is assumed
>   that the machine will have a service account with all necessary roles
>   to access said APIs and determine if the user is OK or not.

The client side browser will include the ID Token in an HTTP header, hidden form field, session state, etc. when communicating with your services. To validate the ID Token you call an endpoint specific to the Identity Provider. For Google the endpoint is: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo`, for Auth0 it is: `https://<replace_with_your_account_name>.auth0.com/userinfo`. These endpoints both validate the integrity of the ID Token. The ID Token contains details about the user that the user authorized you to view. The ID Token, which is a JWT, looks like this when decoded for Google:

```
iss: https://accounts.google.com
azp: <removed_for_security>.apps.googleusercontent.com
aud: <removed_for_security>.apps.googleusercontent.com
sub: <removed_for_security>
hd: example.com
email: username@example.com.com
email_verified: true
at_hash: 63I_abcdefabcdefbi5NSw
nonce: e8TP-uLoEoeXpbk5
name: User Name
picture: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9PtQwhKbOPc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/<removed_for_security>/s96-c/photo.jpg
given_name: User
family_name: Name
locale: en
iat: 1548357229
exp: 1548360829
jti: <removed_for_security>
```

It will be the responsibility of your backend to map the user's identity to whatever privileges you want. You can use a database, etc. for storing this information. If the user is also an Google IAM user, you can generate short-lived credentials based upon IAM privileges stored in Google IAM. However, I only recommend this for a cases where you have only a few users. For hundreds or thousands of users, do not use Google IAM, instead manage this via your Identity Provider thru custom claims or in your own custom database.

> 3) If the user is OK then a session will be created on the Backend for
>   the user and as long as that session lives the Backend will know the
>   identity of the requests, so everything should be fine.

I am not sure what you are trying to say here. For Google Cloud, your backend would either make requests on behalf of the client using its service account or the backend would create a short-lived access token that grants access.

> 1) my approach makes sense and this is even possible?

Your approach is very close to how it should be done. There are some fine details that you do not understand yet, and I hope my answers points you in the right direction to research more.

> 2) if so then what resources or methods I should use to make it
>   happen?

- Decide on the type of OAuth that you will implement (Implicit or 3-legged).
- Decide on the Identity Provider. Google, Facebook, Auth0, etc.
- Decided on the type of code you will embed in the browser (simple JavaScript or a library)
- Decide how to you will pass tokens via HTTP headers, hidden form fields, etc.
- Decide how you will authorize requests. Your own service account or short-lived access tokens created per user.
- Decide how you will translate the ID Token identity into your your set of permissions.

> 3) if not then what approach would be appropriate for my use case?

Your approach is fine and is typical of what we do in the real world.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Authentication with Google as Auth provider is not a problem, I am able to get a user's info after the user is redirected and logs in with their account. The problem I am facing is on the backend. I did not find any documentation or example which shows how to verify that the user (as a Google Identity) belongs to the GCloud organization the project lives under or if the user belongs to a group and has certain roles. The solution I am implementing is enterprise, all the users will have a Google account and only through it will they login, no database involved.

Comment: To continue on what I have written previously the authentication and authorization has to live exclusively inside Google Cloud. What I am missing is the specific APIs I would need to call as a backend service in order to get info on the user within that organization. Everything IAM exposes seems useless in this regard.

Comment: The ID Token as the key `hd: example.com`. This tells you what domain the user is part of. For G Suite, this is the G Suite domain. Nothing in the ID Token will tell you that the user is part of GCP. You have to match the email address or `sub` to a GCP IAM user account. I would create one new question for each item that you need information on. Close your current question as it is very broad.